# On "replay XHR" in developer tools, Form Data is lost

Tags: microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge, new behavior. On the Network tab in Developer Tools, when I right-click a network item and choose "Replay XHR" on a request that includes form data, the form data isn't included in the new request. Makes debugging really, really slow.

This is the first time I've encountered this. Before it always worked. Is there a setting I hit accidentally, without knowing it?

I can "Save as Fetch" and that works, but it's slower than replaying.

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? I can't reproduce the issue. The form data also shows in new request. How do you send the form data in xhr? Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue? So that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: Edge 93, but as I've worked I think I've figured out the pattern, and it's not a bug, per se. If for whatever reason the request couldn't be finished and no response data was returned, it was *that* request I couldn't replay. If I was careful only to choose those with response data, it worked fine.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you have figured it out. You can put it as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Answer added. Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for whatever reason the request can't be finished and no response data is returned, that request cannot be replayed. If one only chooses those with response data, it works as expected.